# Sometimes image spans are not visible when content covers multiple lines in textview

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I have a textview and I am trying to draw image spans along with some text in it.

Sometimes some of the images are not visible when the content wraps to the next line.

Anything that I should keep in mind while adding spans to a textview ?

Any other details i should furnish , I can paste my code here.

Comment: how do you add ImageSpans?

Comment: I am using a StringBuilder object and adding a ' '(space) for every span i want to add. Then setting the span using - 

builder.setSpan(is, end, end + 1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
where is is an ImageSpan , and end points to the space to be replaced.

Comment: So , there is a development I replaced the ' ' by a ':' and everything is working fine.

So , the only question is what is the difference in using a ' ' or a ':' in this context.

Comment: @VinayakBhavnani I was having the same problem and using ':' instead of space worked! This is very odd.

Comment: @WindsurferOak , yes it is odd. And I have not faced any issue with ':' so I havn't tried to dig into it. Do post an explanation if you find one. cheers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So , there is a development I replaced the ' ' by a ':' and everything is working fine. So , the only question is what is the difference in using a ' ' or a ':' in this context.

Comment: My guess is that Android treats whitespace differently at the end of a line (possibly doesn't bother typesetting/rendering it) and the fact that you replace it with an image span isn't taken into consideration, although it probably should. Thank you for your answer (you should mark this as the accepted answer, btw) it really helped me with the same issue!

Comment: Even if it makes no visual difference in the end, but if you are afraid the ":" might show through some freak bug in your spanning code, adding a non breaking space works too, simply add "\u00A0" to your SpannableStringBuilder.